# Aeson Encoding nested records

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Suppose there's this record:

```
data Place = Place
  { details :: PlaceDetails
  , amenities :: [Amenity]
  , photos :: [PlacePhoto]
  } deriving (Generic)
```

I've implemented `toEncoding` for every data type, but I'd like to combine those fields in the `Place` type.
For now, it's like this:

```
instance ToJSON Place where
  toEncoding Place{..} = 
    pairs  $ "details" .= details
          <> "amenities" .= amenities
          <> "photos" .= photos
```

I use `toEncoding` to preserve a certain order that I want. However, I'd like to remove that `details` key from the encoding, so that all the fields from `PlaceDetails` are on the same level as `amenities` and `photos`, without manually specifying all those fields, as `PlaceDetails` is quite big. 
How would I do that? I know that I can merge `[Value]` using `HML.unions` but I've only managed to do that with `toJSON`, not `toEncoding`.

What I currently have:

```
{
    "details": {
        "id": "place_6de6cda0f8524a6f9c264c84afdbadad",
        "name":"somename",
        "description":"some description", 
        "other": "a lot more fields"
    }
    "amenities": []
    "photos": []
}
```

This is what I want:

```
{
    "id":"place_6de6cda0f8524a6f9c264c84afdbadad",
    "name":"somename",
    "description":"some description", 
    "other": "a lot more fields",
    "amenities": []
    "photos": []
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you mean by "on the same level". Can you provide some portion of `PlaceDetails` and what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: Convert `details` to an `Object` so you can then adjust its encoding with `amenities` and `photos`.

Answer (score 1):

An Aeson Object is just a hashmap which you can union using `<>` (infix) or `mappend`.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
    build-depends: base, aeson
-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}

module Main where

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

main :: IO ()
main = print (encode (Place (Foo 1 2) (Bar 3 4)))

data Foo = Foo {foo1 :: Int, foo2 :: Int}
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Generic,ToJSON)

data Bar = Bar {bar1 :: Int, bar2 :: Int}
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Generic,ToJSON)

data Place = Place { foo :: Foo , bar :: Bar }
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Generic)

instance ToJSON Place where
  toJSON Place{..} =
       let Object b = toJSON bar
       in Object ([("foo",toJSON foo)] <> b)
```

And we can run this:

```
% chmod +x so.hs && ./so.hs
... snippet out build info ...
"{\"bar1\":3,\"foo\":{\"foo2\":2,\"foo1\":1},\"bar2\":4}"
```